# Java file path not found

Tags: java

I am using Java8 with Spring running on a Wildfly server.

I have the following package:

[image]

In `LanguageChunkerServiceImpl`, I am trying to get a handle on `en-parser-chunking.bin`, but I get a error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: en-parser-chunking.bin (The system
>   cannot find the file specified)

My code:

**LanguageChunkerServiceImpl.java**

```
new FileInputStream("en-parser-chunking.bin");
```

or

```
new FileInputStream("./src/main/java/com/jobs/spring/service/lang/en-parser-chunking.bin");
```

When I run this from the `main` method, the following does work though:

```
new FileInputStream("./src/main/java/com/jobs/spring/service/lang/en-parser-chunking.bin");
```

Can anyone please advise what the path should be?

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871051/getting-the-current-working-directory-in-java Find your root path and navigate to it.

Comment: You probably want to take a look at [Class#getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914375/getting-file-path-in-java) can help you

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, `ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
   URL resource = classLoader.getResource("en-parser-chunking.bin");`  but `resource` is `null`

Comment: I would rather not get the absolute path of the current location, and then deprive the required files location from there. I think this may not work when I deploy to other servers.

Comment: @mena thanks, I am not sure if I'm using it correctly, but the following returns `null`.  `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("en-parser-chunking.bin")`

Comment: The path of your resource is `com/jobs/spring/service/lang/en-parser-chunking.bin`, not `en-parser-chunking.bin`. And it's not a system resource. Just a plain resource.

Comment: Use **Class**.getResourceAsStream as Mena suggested, not ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the file in resource folder not in src/java, if your using spring.

Answer (score 0):

The [following](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/) works:

If you are using Spring, put the file in the resources dir.

```
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("en-parser-chunking.bin").getFile());
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        modelInParse = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
```